# how to create e-mail template for outlook 2010 with a text over an image

Tags: outlook, outlook-2010, oft

I'm trying to create .oft template for outlook 2010 with a text over an image - text should be customisable by the end users...

[image: example]

If I create new e-mail from a html file and save it as template, input is not editable (using just a normal styled paragraph)

If I create new e-mail template directly in outlook, everything is ok for users, but it doesn't send it properly - everything is send as an attachment - so it doesn't display it properly in some mail clients (e.g. gmail).

Is there any bullet proof way how to create e-mail templates for outlook 2010 ?

Answer (score 0):

I made a Fiddle so you can see this code in action: https://jsfiddle.net/wallyglenn/7zLaLrfx/

```
<div style="background-color:#ff0000; width:600px;">
  <!--[if gte mso 9]>
  <v:background xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="t">
    <v:fill type="tile" src="http://www.gwally.com/news/photos/catintinfoilhat.jpg" color="#ff0000"/>
  </v:background>
  <![endif]-->
  <table height="450" width="600" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <tr>
      <td valign="top" align="left" background="http://www.gwally.com/news/photos/catintinfoilhat.jpg">
        <h1 style="text-align: center; color: #ffffff;-webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px; -webkit-text-stroke-color: black; font-family: Arial, san-serif;">
          Background Image with text on top
        </h1>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

The original code was taken from https://backgrounds.cm.

Good luck.

Comment: thanks, that's exactly what I meant about importing html - when I send this directly it's ok. But when I open it in outlook and save it as .oft file, it somehow modifies it and then send everything in attachment.